# In mysql is it advisible to rely on uniqueness constraints or to manually check if the row is already present?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table:

```
userId | subject
```

with uniqueness constraint on both combined.

Now I am writing thousands of rows to this table every few minutes. The data stream is coming from a queue and it might repeat. I have to however make sure that there is only one unique combination of userId,subject in the table.

Currently I rely on mysql's uniqueness constraint which throws as exception.

Another approach is run a SELECT count(*) query to check if this row is already present and then skip it if need be.

Since I want to write on an average 4 rows per second what is advisable.

Programming language: Java

**EDIT:**

Just in case I am not clear the question here is whether relying ton MYSQL to throw an exception is better or running a select query before insert operation is better in terms of performance.

I thought a select query is less CPU/IO intensive than a INSERT query. If I run too many INSERTS wouldn't that create many locks ?

Comment: there's no way to disable a unique constraint. you can't guarantee that someone else might not insert a record behind your back that'd cause a violation, but mysql won't allow a unique constraint to be violated.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is ACID and employs transactional locking, so relying on its uniqueness constraints is very standard. Note that you can do this either via PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY (but favour the former if you can).

Comment: Thanks Aaron but my question refers to performance rather than reliability.

Comment: I see. Given that you must have a PK on the table, wouldn't any other uniqueness checking just add inefficiency? Let me know if I'm not understanding.

Comment: I think INSERT queries on mysql table (MYISAM) locks the whole table so I assume all the insert queries have to be run sequentially. If 100% of insert queries succeed than this is the best we can do. But in case 90% of INSERT queries fail because of uniqueness criteria I think we can run SELECT queries which can happen in parallel and then run INSERT queries only for the 10%.

Comment: I am thinking of this as a entry to a place where there is only one door and one bouncer at the door to check the tickets. 90% of people are sent back by the bouncer and only one person can enter at a time. The lines for such a place will be simply too long. What if I have 10 other lines for ticket checking and only people with valid tickets are sent to the main door ?

Answer (score 2):

A unique constraint is unique for the complete committed dataset.

There a several databases which allows to set "transaction isolation level".

```
userId    subject
A         1
B         2
-------------------------
A         2
A         3
```

The two rows above the line are committed. Every connection can read these lines. The two line under the line are currently been written within your transaction. Within this connection all four lines are visible.

If another thread / connection / transaction tries to store A-2 there will be an exception in one of the two transaction (the first one can commit the transaction, the second one can't).

Other isolation level may fail earlier. But it is not possible to violate against the Unique-key constraint.

Comment: But if there are many threads writing wouldn't it mean each one of them will wait for a lock ? In my case I expect 80% of INSERTS to violate uniqueness constraint and hence fail. 
Do you think performance wise it is better for me to first run a select query and try to top kill these 80% of INSERT and then use mysql uniqueness constraint as fall back ?

Comment: So you question is more about performance than reliability or a unique key?

Comment: My question is about performance and not reliability. I can not make batch updates. Would answer depend on whether or not batch updates are possible ?